# How to split a column in excel file using VBScript?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

In one column of my excel file I have a data as follows. 
APRPT, APTRNA, APTRNC, APTRNI, APTRNR, APTRNT, CBRPT, GLRPT, INRPT, PORPT, POTRNR.

I want to split the above data from one column to individual columns.There are almost 500 rows with the similar data. How can we do this using VBScript?

I have code for selecting the excel file and column, but stuck after that!

```
Set objExcel = Wscript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")   
Set objWorkbook = 
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tnookala\Documents\Book.xlsx")   
objExcel.visible=True
rowCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count
colCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.count  

objExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns(4).Select
 Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
```

Loop

Comment: Are you saying that in cell A1 you have this string - "APRPT, APTRNA, APTRNC, APTRNI, APTRNR, APTRNT, CBRPT, GLRPT, INRPT, PORPT, POTRNR" and that string is repeated 500 times in the rows below. If so, and your desired result is APRPT in column A, APTRNA in column B, and so on, then the 'Text to Columns' feature will work. No VBA is needed. If this is not the case, then please explain your question in more detail.

Comment: I have similar data which needed to be split, they are not repeating 500 times.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments: edit your question to add the code, and use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: you can use `Range.TextToColumns` for that

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use VBA, then the following will work.
This selects column A, and splits from there. You can adjust as suits.

```
Range("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True
```

Comment: Sorry NMS. You will need to be more specific if you want help here. I would suggest writing your question more clearly and giving more detail as to why this isn't working. e.g. are you getting an error message? where have you put the code? what happens when you debug?

Comment: Sorry Chris. i was getting error as expected statement at :=Range

Comment: Are you aware of the text to columns feature under the data tab? Have you tried using that? If so and it works, maybe try recording a macro and see the code that it writes. Its a little hard to work out what is going wrong for you. I assume that you are running this code on a open workbook... If not, perhaps try modifing it to this {Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True}